# How to deploy my web application to jetty9 as root application?

Tags: jetty

When I use jetty6, I use the following:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">


  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Required minimal context configuration :                        -->
  <!--  + contextPath                                                  -->
  <!--  + war OR resourceBase                                          -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/myapp</Set>

</Configure>
```

this file located in folder contexts,named myapp.xml

But switch to jetty 9, first there is no such folder "contexts", and I put myapp.xml into webapps just like test.xml, restart jetty and navigate to `http://localhost:8080`, the page remain the default one, not my application.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Answer (score 19):

In Jetty 6, if you had

```
${jetty.home}/contexts/myapp.xml
```

With Jetty 9.0, move it to

```
${jetty.home}/webapps/myapp.xml
```

With Jetty 9.1+, move it to

```
${jetty.base}/webapps/myapp.xml
```

Make sure the exploded webapp directory is the same name as your xml file to prevent double deployment.

You also need to change your Context XML File for Jetty 9.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
          "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/webapps/myapp</Set>
</Configure>
```

Or alternatively, just name your exploded webapp directory

```
${jetty.home}/webapps/ROOT
```

Documentation found:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-deployment.html

*Updated for Jetty 9.1*

Comment: Thanks, seems working,form the log I can see my app deployed,but the page of "http://localhost:8080" is still the default one.I want my application is the root application.

Comment: A tad late, but for reference: this method works, but *only* if you **move or rename the existing webapps/root directory**. Source: did not find it in the documentation, i.e., trial and error. I'm using jetty 9.2 on Debian/stretch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the specially named `/root` or `root.war`.  See [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.1.3.v20140225/automatic-webapp-deployment.html) .

Comment: I guess the correct link is now https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications#Deploying_Webapps